# How to use Views pages in entity reference

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, entityreference

I have created a page in views. Is it possible to use Views pages in entity reference field. I can able to use content types, but unable to use Views pages. Can anyone please help me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the view to populate the dropdown for an entity reference or do you want to display something from a referenced entity in your view page?

Comment: If we use entity reference field, all the pages created from the content types (Article, Basic page, etc... ) will be displayed in the entity reference dropdown field. But the pages created from views is not displaying in the field.